# Помогите реализовать слайдер или подскажите с помощью какого плагина можно сделать

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slick.js

Нужно реализовать вот такой слайдер, кто сталкивался ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь за вас код не пишут.

Comment: Я Вас код прошу писать ? Я прошу подсказать

Comment: Если есть гифка, как слайдер анимируется, то кидай

Comment: @ВладимирЛиподат хочу сказать что это вебсайт по решению проблем связанный с программированию, вопросы формата "сделай за меня" или "совет" не очень подходят под этот веб сайт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var button_prev = document.querySelector('.prev')
var button_next = document.querySelector('.next')
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide')
var counter = document.querySelector('.counter')

var cur = slides.length - 1;
setCounter()

button_prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (cur < slides.length - 1) prev()
})

button_next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (cur > 0) next()
})

function next() {
  slides[cur].classList.add('prev-slide')
  slides[cur - 1].classList.remove('next-slide')
  cur--
  setCounter()
}

function prev() {
  slides[cur].classList.add('next-slide')
  slides[cur + 1].classList.remove('prev-slide')
  cur++
  setCounter()
}

function setCounter() {
  counter.innerText = `${Math.abs(cur - slides.length)} / ${slides.length}`
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.slider {
  height: 80%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide-list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  transition: 1s;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.buttons {
  height: 10%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.counter {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.next {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

.next-slide {
  transform: translateX(100%) translateZ(-700px);
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: -1;
}

.prev-slide {
  transform: translateY(100%) translateZ(-700px);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide-list">
    <div class="slide next-slide">
      <img src="https://www.karandash.by/file/previewdesign/5299">
    </div>
    <div class="slide next-slide">
      <img src="https://worldbreastfeedingweek.org/2019/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/certificate-1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide next-slide">
      <img src="https://cdn.bitdegree.org/assets/certificate-example.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://www.diplomacompany.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/48282d7234173eec92424c7aed31f915/f/a/fake-massage-therapist-certificate.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="prev"></button>
    <span class="counter"></span>
    <button class="next"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот так поприкольнее по моему:

```js
var button_prev = document.querySelector('.prev')
var button_next = document.querySelector('.next')
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide')
var counter = document.querySelector('.counter')

var cur = slides.length - 1;
setCounter()

button_prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (cur < slides.length - 1) prev()
})

button_next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (cur > 0) next()
})

function next() {
  slides[cur].classList.add('prev-slide')
  slides[cur - 1].classList.remove('next-slide')
  cur--
  setCounter()
}

function prev() {
  slides[cur].classList.add('next-slide')
  slides[cur + 1].classList.remove('prev-slide')
  cur++
  setCounter()
}

function setCounter() {
  counter.innerText = `${Math.abs(cur - slides.length)} / ${slides.length}`
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.slider {
  height: 80%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide-list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  transition: 1s;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.buttons {
  height: 10%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.counter {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.next {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

.next-slide {
  transform: translateY(100%) translateZ(-700px);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.prev-slide {
  transform: translateX(100%) translateZ(-700px);
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide-list">
    <div class="slide next-slide">
      <img src="https://www.karandash.by/file/previewdesign/5299">
    </div>
    <div class="slide next-slide">
      <img src="https://worldbreastfeedingweek.org/2019/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/certificate-1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide next-slide">
      <img src="https://cdn.bitdegree.org/assets/certificate-example.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://www.diplomacompany.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/48282d7234173eec92424c7aed31f915/f/a/fake-massage-therapist-certificate.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="prev"></button>
    <span class="counter"></span>
    <button class="next"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!)

Comment: Как зациклить этот слайд ?)

Comment: @ВладимирЛиподат потом если будет время напишу

Comment: ок, спасибо,  попробую сам разобраться, а то завтра надо сдать правку)